# Angular JS controller property not evaluated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have a component with a controller and template. Properties from the controller are being replaced in the template when they are between html tags, but not as tag attributes.

So given this component:

```
  angular.module('OeApp').component('phonemeComponent', {
    templateUrl: '/src/templates/phoneme.template.html',
    controller: 'PhonemeController as ctrl',
    bindings: {
      exercise: '<'
    }
  })
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('OeApp').controller('PhonemeController', PhonemeController);

function PhonemeController() {
  var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.listenButtonUrl = "/images/speaker-button-sm.gif"; 
};
```

Template snippet:

```
<div id="phoneticSymbol">{{ctrl.exercise.phoneticSymbol}}</div>

<!-- sample word -->
<img class="listenButton" src="ctrl.listenButtonUrl"></img>

<div id="oeWord">{{ctrl.exercise.sampleWordOE}}</div>
<div id="modWord">({{ctrl.exercise.sampleWordModE}})</div>
```

The `phoneticSymbol`, `oeWord`, and `modWord` are all replaced as expected, but `src` for the img is the literal string `"ctrl.listenButtonUrl"`. What am I missing?

I tried enclosing `ctrl.listenButtonUrl` in curly braces, even though that's not how it works in other sample code, and the browser first tries to resolve the literal string as a url (resulting in a **404**), but eventually gets the right value, so I don't think that's the right solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

```
<img class="listenButton" ng-src="{{ctrl.listenButtonUrl}}"></img>
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me understand why I still need the curly braces, when in other situations I don't? Eg, for ng-show here:

<div ng-show="list.errorMessage" class="error">Error: {{list.errorMessage}}</div>

Comment: @Sasha HTML is trying to be smart and tries to fetch src content (which is literally `{{ctrl.listenButtonUrl}}`) before AngularJS can replace it with your actual value that needs to be fetched. You still need braces because `ng-src="some/path/{{url}}"` links are allowed